# SELECT and ADD fields in SQL table

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a db table created as follows :

```
CREATE TABLE mktDB(
mktID number(19) not null,
featureId number(20) not null,
val varchar(100) not null,
primary key (id)
);
```

I want to view all the records along with an additional field having current date with each row in the db.

I tried the following sqlite query but it is erroneous :

```
SELECT *, CURRENT_DATE FROM mktDB,DATE;
```

Comment: Do you have a table called `DATE` in your schema, or do you just want to also `SELECT` the current date?

Comment: I want to select the current date. There is no table named DATE.

Answer (score 3):

Don't know SQLite very well but after typing "current date sqllite" in google it shows me the way to 
https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

and for your problem:

```
 SELECT *, date('now') FROM mktDB;
```

P.S:
I always wanted to try SQL fiddle. So here it is:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/92fd6/3

Answer (score 1):

Please use below query

```
SELECT *, date('now') FROM mktDB
```

Comment: This is not valid SQL.

Comment: Please remove the space between them i have tested its working for me. Are you using mysql??

Comment: Why would you use MySQL for a question about SQLite?

Comment: Sorry late me convert it to sqllite

Answer (score 1):

1) The function is date('now')

2) You don't need to select from DATE

```
SELECT *, date('now') FROM mktDB;
```